# Angular 5 short circuit a route to show a different component

Tags: angular5

I have a condition that I may need to short circuit a route and show a different component than the one specified in the route configuration.  I don't want to redirect to a different route because what I really want to do it display an error component.  I don't want to add code to every route component to display an error message, I just want to be able to show the error component instead of the route's configured component.  CanActivate doesn't seem to be much help as all it returns is a boolean or I can navigate to a new route within the CanActivate method handler which I don't want to do.  Is there a router override that I can use?